# Troubles with addressing a 2-dimensional hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to reference a 2-dimensional hash. Does anyone know why the below would not output `true` and how to change it so that it will?

```
grid = Hash.new(false)
grid [[3,2]] = true
current_position = [3,2]
puts grid[[current_position]]
```

Comment: That is not a two-dimensional hash, it is a hash with a key that happens to be an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key in your hash is `[3,2]` which is equivalent to `current_position`, so to access the contents, it's:

```
puts grid[current_position]
```